# Ubuntu php mkdir

Tags: php, ubuntu, permissions, mkdir, umask

I'm trying to create a directory but I get the wrong permissions everytime it creates the new directory.

Permissions on the file creating the folder:

```
rwxr-xr-x
```

Permission on the folder its trying to create it in

```
rwxr-xr-x
```

Both are owned by www-data www-data

I try to create the folder with php

```
mkdir(location,0775);
```

Result after running the script

```
r-----rwt
```

I ran out of reasons to believe it went wrong.

umask is on 002.

Hope somebody can help me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$location = "path/to/you/dir";
$uold     = umask(0);

mkdir($location,0777,true);
umask($uold);
```

give that a try and see what it says...

Comment: then try 0777 it should (after the application of the mask) give you 775 - rwxrwxr-x

Comment: Will end up as 407 still (r-----rwt , not sure what the t means though)

Comment: hmmm perhaps this is something on the permissions the user php is running under has...

Comment: Where should I look? it runs as www-data and everything is owned by www-data

Comment: switch to that user and try and create a directory in the command line. Just as an experiment - have you tried chmod after mkdir?